# Django dropdown error even value is selected

Tags: django, forms, dropdown

Hello Really having hard time, to figure out why form.is_valid() showing false. 
Here is the code:
MODEL

```
class Config(ValidateOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    dcsubnet = models.ForeignKey(Add_Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dcurl = models.CharField(max_length=35, default='')
    dcsvrip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', default='', unique=True)
```

FORM:

```
class GenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dc_dcnmurl = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Add_Site.objects.order_by('dcnmURL').values_list('dcnmURL', flat=True).distinct())
    dcsvrip = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Add_Site.objects.order_by('dcIP').values_list('dcIP', flat=True).distinct())
    dcsubnet = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Add_Site.objects.order_by('subnet').values_list('subnet', flat=True).distinct())

    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = '__all__'
        field_classes = {
            'json_field': JSONFormField,
        }
```

VIEW:

```
def dc_config(request):
   form = GenForm(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        print("FORM is VALID: {}".format(form.is_valid()))
        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
           task = form.save(commit=False)
           messages.success(request, 'Successfully stored data into database.')
           return render(request, template_name, {'form': form })
        else:
            pprint(form.errors)
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
```

HTML:

```
<form id="config" role=form method="POST" class="post-form" action="config">{% csrf_token %}

<div name="dcsubnet" class="dropdown" id="dropdownselection" required> {{ form.subnet }</div>
<div name="dcnmurl" class="dropdown" id="dropdownselection" required> {{ form.dcurl }}
</div>
<div name="dcnm_server_ip" class="dropdown" id="dropdownselection" required>{{ form.dcsrvip }}</div>
</form>
```

Keep getting error that form is not valid.

```
FORM is VALID: False
{'dcurl': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'],
 'dcsrvip': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'],
 'dcsubnet': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

Comment: Print the form data and check if it's one of the choices.

Comment: I did set the alert via jquery 
``` $("#dcsrvip").change(function() { var dropdownselected = $("#dcsrvip option:selected").text(); )}; ```
I can see the value correctly, but it doesn't pass the form.validate